# How to get the embedded schema id from a Kafka message using a CLI tool?

Tags: apache-kafka, command-line-interface, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

How to get the embedded schema id from a Kafka message using a CLI tool?

I am trying using `kcat` and I can parse pointing to my Schema Registry, but for debugging purposes, I want to get it in bytes and parse the schema id out of the message.

[It is known that the id is in the 1-4 bytes.](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format) How can I parse the bytes and extract the id from my own terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --property print.schema.ids=true
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/901

Comment: Thank you. As a side question: from your experience what are the main differences between kafka console and kcat CLIs?

Comment: Main difference? C vs Java, mostly. The Java API has priority for features. The C clients are more lightweight...